# Networkx and graphviz. How to suppress node and edge positions in dot output?

Tags: networkx, pygraphviz

Take this simple networkx script.

```
import networkx as nx

g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_edge("a","b")
g.add_edge("a","c")
g.add_node("D")

dotter = nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(g)
dotter.layout("dot")
dot = dotter.to_string()

with open("test_w_pos.dot","w") as fo:
    fo.write(dot)
```

The output is:

```
strict digraph "" {
    graph [bb="0,0,162,108"];
    node [label="\N"];
    a    [height=0.5,
        pos="63,90",
        width=0.75];
    b    [height=0.5,
        pos="27,18",
        width=0.75];
    a -> b   [pos="e,35.634,35.269 54.285,72.571 50.04,64.081 44.846,53.693 40.134,44.267"];
    c    [height=0.5,
        pos="99,18",
        width=0.75];
    a -> c   [pos="e,90.366,35.269 71.715,72.571 75.96,64.081 81.154,53.693 85.866,44.267"];
    D    [height=0.5,
        pos="135,90",
        width=0.75];
}
```

I'd like to **not** have any of the `pos`, `height` and `width` attributes as they vary from run to run and make it hard to compare to previous runs on complex graphs.

#### desired output

```
strict digraph "" {
    node [label="\N"];
    a;
    b;
    a -> b;
    c;
    a -> c;
    D;
}
```

Both `dot` files give substantially the same output in `svg` (see below), so I find the positioning unnecessary and in fact I've never seen this information put into `dot` files previously.

I could not find anything in `to_agraph` or `dotter.to_string`, but I did not notice extra arguments are possible in `dotter.layout(dot)`:

#### agraph.py

```
    def layout(self, prog="neato", args=""):
        """Assign positions to nodes in graph.
```

Yes, with this very simplistic file, I could drop the positioning data afterwards.  But in a real graph, there will be a lot of other color and label attributes mixed in with the positions.

#### image with position attributes:

[image]

#### image without position attributes:

[image]

Comment: How about [`nx.write_dot`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot.html)?

Comment: @Sparky05.  I'd accept it if you write an answer.   `nx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot(g, "test_write_dot.dot")` is what I used.  I did have to install [py_dot](https://pypi.org/project/pydot/) but it's pure Python so that's also attractive compared to **pygraphviz** which required some tweaking before pip found the appropriate **graphviz/cgraph.h** which was giving errors before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only interested in the `dot` file you can use the [`pydot`](https://github.com/pydot/pydot) interface of `networkx` and call [`write_dot`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot.html#), e.g.

```
drawing.nx_pydot.write_dot(g, "test.dot")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `dotter.layout("canon")`  (https://graphviz.org/docs/outputs/canon/).  This will provide a (pretty printed) version of your graph without any positioning.

Comment: Didn't work.  Got `ValueError: Program canon is not one of: neato, dot, twopi, circo, fdp, nop, wc, acyclic, gvpr, gvcolor, ccomps, sccmap, tred, sfdp, unflatten.`